# how to use the data that got back from mongodb instead of returning it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I want to process my data that I retreived from my mongodb, before I return it through my api.

My api-request is like this:

```
.get('/users', function(req, res){
    var users = [];
    User.find({}, function(err, data){
        if(err) res.send(err);
        users = data;
    }

    // here I want to do some things with the users

    res.json(users);
}
```

However, users got undefined... 
My guess is that the code runs forward, before the response got back to efectively fill 'users'
What i the right way to wait until the variable is filled to be able to use the contents?
Or is it not a waiting mather, but a different error?

Comment: I am aware it would be a duplicate question, however I didn't know what to look for... (had no ID this was synchronous...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.find({}, function(err, data){
        if(err) res.send(err);
        users = data;
    }
```

The above code will run asynchronously, so you are expecting result before its get finished.

So try for this:

```
    .get('/users', function(req, res){
        var users = [];
        User.find({}, function(err, data){
            if(err) res.send(err);
            users = data;

         //  do some things with the users

        res.json(users);
        }    
}
```